# How to enable APM in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed Kibana7.7 and have trouble to enable APM. I followed this instruction: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/apm-settings-kb.html and added below configuration:

```
xpack.apm.enabled: true
xpack.apm.ui.enabled: true
```

when run the command `bin/kibana serve` but get below error:

```
 log   [12:52:34.607] [fatal][root] { Error: Unknown configuration key(s): "xpack.apm.enabled", "xpack.apm.ui.enabled". Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed.
    at ensureValidConfiguration (/home/ubuntu/dev/kibana-7.7.0-linux-x86_64/src/core/server/legacy/config/ensure_valid_configuration.js:46:11) code: 'InvalidConfig', processExitCode: 64, cause: undefined }

 FATAL  Error: Unknown configuration key(s): "xpack.apm.enabled", "xpack.apm.ui.enabled". Check for spelling errors and ensure that expected plugins are installed.
```

Did I make anything wrong?

Comment: Which binaries for Elasticsearch and Kibana did you download? The APM UI isn't part of all of them, so that might be a problem.

Comment: I am using 7.7 for both Elasticsearch and Kibana

Comment: Yes, but which binary? There is more than one and not all include this feature. Do you have the link of where you downloaded it or what does `curl localhost:9200` (against Elasticearch) tell you?

Comment: Elasticsearch is the AWS hosted cluster. Kibana is downloaded from https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-7.7.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: There seems to be a license mismatch between the AWS Elasticsearch service and the self-hosted Kibana with the default binary.

The AWS ES service uses the OSS base and that cannot be combined with the default non-OSS Kibana (the APM UI is part of the free but not OSS portion of the Elastic Stack).

Your options are to either host a free default binary of Elasticsearch yourself or switch to [Elastic Cloud](https://cloud.elastic.co).

PS: I haven't checked the log output for that scenario recently, but I would have expected a log message about the license mismatch somewhere in there.